# Slow/incomplete page load in the browser launched by selenium webdriver

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, robotframework

I am using selenium WebDriver using RobotFramework. The major problem we are facing is, my tests are timing out even after setting timeout as high as 10 minutes. It happen with any browser I use. These thing works much faster If I run test manually (with all browser cache/data/cookie cleared). These are the other things I have observing for few months.

- Some component are never loaded (I check the call trace using BrowserMob Proxy and we found nothing unusual)
- "Click Element" does not work in many cases. Clicking on element triggers some action but that action is not always trigerred in automation. Manually it works all the time.

Notes:

- This is happening on FF and Chrome. (IE is not working for me at all)
- App server and automation suite is in LAN so latency is not an issue
- No other heavy process is running at this time
- Issue persist even if with firefox default profile
- I tried it with different selenium versions. (2.45 - 2.52)
- I took latest driver for chrome. Broweser: FF 40+ and GC 48

This does not look application issue as we spent 2 month confirming that. Let me know if you need any other detail.

Comment: Do you watch the browsers to see what they are doing and what they are displaying while waiting for the timeout?

Comment: Yes @BryanOakley, I do watch them. After certain point page remain just like that till it times out.

Comment: can you share that particular part of code, or be sure that something going wrong there..

Comment: Clicking on an element not working like manual can be caused by the automation going too fast - native events and the element moved before Selenium could click on it (and thus clicked on something else) or also so fast that the JavaScript handling that interaction has not bound to the event before the click occurred.

Comment: @ombre42, I agree for the case element not clickable. In this case it should throw JS error. Let me see if I can capture JS error somehow. But still, the issue of page does not load all component (and is slow) is still there. Any suggestion here